# man command: is there a way to know the meaning of the output of a command >

Tags: linux, command-line, man

Is there a way to know the meaning of the output of a command?

Example given: If I type `ls -l`, I get this ouput:

```
[root@localhost junk]# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1862 2012-08-25 16:20 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2012-08-25 15:41 a.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1907 2012-08-25 16:18 b
```

Now I want to know here what all these fields (e.g. `-rw-r--r--`, 1862) stand for.

Is there a way to do that using `man`?

Comment: This question is overly broad.  Are you asking about GNU `ls` or about "all" commands?

Comment: Commands/help in general. I put `ls` as an example.

Comment: The most valid answer here though does deal with `ls` (and perhaps a handful of other things) specifically.  Usually this is *exactly* the kind of information that should be in the man page.  In this case it's not because GNU's version of `ls` is non-standard and GNU seems to have had a historical preference for documenting things with `info` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `info` command to know more details about any command in coreutils.

Here is some portion in `info ls`, explain the `-l` option:

```
`-l'
`--format=long'
`--format=verbose'
     In addition to the name of each file, print the file type, file
     mode bits, number of hard links, owner name, group name, size, and
     timestamp (*note Formatting file timestamps::), normally the
     modification time.  Print question marks for information that
     cannot be determined.
     ........
```

Comment: +1 I was going to reference this but you beat me to it.  There is not an `info` node for "any command", however (there is for everything in the coreutils package).  If there is one, it's usually referred to at the end of the man page.  GNU `ls` has a particularly lame piece of stub as a man page, unfortunately.

Comment: @goldilocks: Oh, of course, my mistake. updated my answer.

Comment: `info ls` on my system (GNU/Linux 2.6.34.3) prints: `
9.1 Defining the Comparison Function
====================================
`. I scrolled down the whole section but there is no `ls`. I have used info before so this is weird, but thanks for your answer. It (`info` certainly is more informative than `man`.